# How to implement Swift 3 Dictionary first(where:) closure

Tags: dictionary, filter, swift3

I have an [String:String] array in Swift 3 and I want to find a specific item in this array depending on whether the Key contains a String value.

```
                let result = collection.first(where: ((key, value) -> Bool in
                    return key.contains("mystring")))
```

However Xcode keeps telling me that it is 'Expected expression in list of expressions'. I googled for an hour now and every website that is using this closure in either a contains or filter manner seems to be the right syntax.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't actually made a closure, because you used `( )` instead of `{ }`

Furthermore, the closure for `first(where:)` has type `(Dictionary<Key, Value>.Iterator.Element) throws -> Bool`. The parameter is a single tuple, which is the `(Key, Value)` pair of the iteration.

Try this, instead:

```
let result = collection.first(where: { pair -> Bool in
    return pair.key.contains("mystring")
})
```

But there are a few simplifications you can make:

1. The `Bool` return type can be inferred.
2. The `return` keyword isn't necessary in single expression closures.
3. The `pair` parameter name is arbitrary and rather meaningless, so it's better to just use implicit closure parameters.
4. Trailling closure syntax can be used.

After these changes, it all simplifies down to just this:

```
let result = collection.first{ $0.key.contains("mystring") }
```